# JavaScript: Options is Nullor not an object

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

Hi i have written a small javascript function and i m getting the Error as `"Options is Null or not an object"`

Here is my code:

```
  function ValidateMarks(sender, args) {
        var ddlCategory = document.getElementById('ctl00_rightContainer_ContentTable2_ddlCategory').value;
        var ddlDisabilityClass = document.getElementById('ctl00_rightContainer_ContentTable2_ddlDisabilityClass').value;
        var GraduationPercntage = document.getElementById('ctl00_rightContainer_ContentTable2_txtGraduationPercntage').value;
        var objCVValidateMarks = document.getElementById("ctl00_rightContainer_cvValidateMarks");

        if ((ddlCategory.options[ddlCategory.selectedIndex].text == "-- Select Category --" || ddlCategory.options[ddlCategory.selectedIndex].text == "UR") && (ddlDisabilityClass.options[ddlDisabilityClass.selectedIndex].text == "No")) {
            if (parseFloat(GraduationPercntage) < parseFloat('49.50')) {
                objCVValidateMarks.errormessage = 'You are required 49.50% marks in B.Pharmacy to fulfill the eligibility.';
                args.IsValid = false;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (parseFloat(GraduationPercntage) < parseFloat('44.50')) {
                objCVValidateMarks.errormessage = 'You are required 44.50% marks in B.Pharmacy to fulfill the eligibility.';
                args.IsValid = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

When i check the value for ddlcategory it gives me the selected value but `ddlCategory.selectedIndex` gives me the value as '`undefined`' hence i m getting the above mentioned error.

Comment: What is your problem/question? Don't you understand the error message? If you want `ddlCategory` to refer to the `select` element instead of the value, then use `var ddlCategory = document.getElementById('...');` instead of `var ddlCategory = document.getElementById('...').value;`

Comment: Btw, you don't get the error because of `ddlCategory.selectedIndex` but because of `ddlCategory.options`.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing ddlCategory from

```
var ddlCategory = document.getElementById('ctl00_rightContainer_ContentTable2_ddlCategory').value;
```

to

```
var ddlCategory = document.getElementById('ctl00_rightContainer_ContentTable2_ddlCategory');
```

Now try getting the value using `ddlCategory.value` and selected Index using `ddlCategory.selectedIndex`

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

It appears you have hardcoded in clientIDs for components.

Is this the case? If so please consider using either this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx , which will allow you (in .NET 4.5, using ClientIDMode="Static") to have sensible never changing clientIDs (but also lets you run the risk of having more than one item with the same ID on the page).

or this:

document.getElementById("<%= MYELEMENT.ClientID %>").

OR if using seperate javascript files then pass in the clientIDs as parameters into your javascript function.

More specifically for your problem it seems that javascript cannot find ddlCategory or ddlDisabilityClass, I would imagine one of these two lines is failing and giving you a null var:

```
var ddlCategory = document.getElementById('ctl00_rightContainer_ContentTable2_ddlCategory').value;
var ddlDisabilityClass = document.getElementById('ctl00_rightContainer_ContentTable2_ddlDisabilityClass').value;
```

It is always good to debug javascript with Alerts when this happens, such as Alert('Object was:'+ddlCategory); This will give you a NULL if it's not found, or tell you specifically what that var is set to.

Looking at this again, your specific problem is that you are getting the values of these objects instead of a reference to the objects themselves. Removing .value from the end of your getElementById calls should fix this (as long as your references are valid).